# Ansible Synchronize With Wildcard

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to synchronize a file with a wildcard:

```
- name: Install Services jar
  synchronize: src="{{repo}}/target/all-services-*.jar" dest=/opt/company
```

I'm doing this so that I don't have to update ansible every time our version number gets bumped. However, this throws a file not found exception when it is run. Does ansible support this? And if so, how can I do it?

Comment: I think its a matter of escaping the * `src="{{repo}}/target/all-services-{{ '*' }}.jar"` I think this may work.

Comment: @rayray84 unfortunately, nope. seems like, when ansible calls rsync, the path is wrapped in double quotes like "foo/target/all-services-*.jar" which breaks wildcard expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with ansible's with_lines:

```
- name: Install services jar
  synchronize: src="{{item}}" dest=/opt/company/
  with_lines: "find {{ core_repo }}/service-packaging/target/ -name all-services*.jar | grep -v original"
```

Comment: Using find is problematic if you want to retain structure of directories.

Answer (score 4):

Ansible module `synchronize` uses `rsync` and supports custom options for `rsync` through parameter `rsync_opts` (since 1.6) which could be used to filter file.

Example:

```
- name: sync source code
  synchronize:
  src: "/path/to/local/src"
  dest: "{{lookup('env','HOME')}}/remote/src"
  rsync_opts:
  - "--include=*.py"
  - "--exclude=*.pyc"
  - "--delete"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using a `with_items` or related, then you might not be able to use `with_lines` instead. For example, if you're trying to run

```
- name: Install Services jar
  synchronize: src="{{repo}}/target/{{ item }}-*.jar" dest=/opt/company
  with_items:
    - service1
    - service2
```

When synchronize invokes rsync, it wraps the `src` and `dest` in quotes which breaks the wildcard/glob expansion.

I've been able to shell out to rsync directly to bypass this behavior.

```
- name: Install Services jar
  shell: rsync -azPihv {{repo}}/target/{{ item }}-*.jar {{ inventory_hostname }}:/opt/company
  register: rsync_cmd
  changed_when: rsync_cmd.stdout.find('xfer') != -1
  with_items:
    - service1
    - service2
```

(You may need to use xfr instead of xfer depending on your rsync.)

Answer (score 0):

If the file name changes automatically and isn't set explicitly in an ansible variable, you'll want to identify the name of the file by some other means. I've seen patterns in which you download the "latest" version of a package (many repositories provide this ability). Then once you have the file, you always name it the same thing locally and you can synchronize that - no need for the wildcard pattern.

Another option could be to look up the latest version of a library in some machine readable registry. Then use that to reference the file by its full name and drive the tasks that require the exact file name.

If I'm misunderstanding your question and you are intending to synchronize multiple files that match your wildcard pattern, you could synchronize the entire directory containing your `src` pattern (`{{repo}}/target/`), then pass arguments directly to `rsync` to filter using a pattern. Via [synchronize module docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) I see you can pass arguments directly to `rsync` by setting `rsync-opts`. In the [rsync docs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) I found online you can pass a flag like `--include=all-services-*.jar` to limit the files you send to just those that match a pattern.

I hope this helps!